# Skylars white's reflection in microwave oven in her last scene in the finale of Breaking Bad?

Tags: analysis, breaking-bad

In the last scene of *Breaking Bad* between Walt and Skylar, her reflection is seen in the window of the microwave oven.

[image]

(It looks to me like it was added as an effect.)  Did any of the writers indicate meaning to her reflection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Vulture.com](https://www.vulture.com/2013/09/breaking-bad-finale-facts-learned-on-talking-bad.html):

> The amazing shot of Skyler reflected in the microwave was completely accidental. Gilligan admits not knowing he got it until the editor complimented it.